# JQuery remove parent node

Tags: jquery

I want to add make an application that user can add as many fieldsets as they want. When user clicks "add", it adds a second filedset with package2. If user clicks the corresponding "delete", it will delete the corresponding fieldset.The application should always has at least one fieldset, which means it can not be deleted if there is only one fieldset on the web. I have finished some of the code here, can someone help me figure out what is wrong with it? Thank you.
https://jsfiddle.net/cowling/2qfy6cct/

HTML code:

```
<form>  
    <div id="fieldwrapper">
      <fieldset class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 bottom20" id="addField">
        <div class="col-md-11">

            <label class="col-md-1 label-right left-0">package1*</label>
            <div class=" col-md-11 input-div " id="tracking">
                <input type="text" class="col-md-11 input-div form-control required" >
            </div>
            <div id="errors" class="txt-left"></div>


            <label class="col-md-1 label-right">comment</label>
            <div class="col-md-11 input-div">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" >      
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove top25" >delete</button>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="add" value="add" >
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">finish</button>
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


   // $('.remove').click(function(){
   //      $(this).parents("fieldset").remove();
   //  });

    $("#add").click(function() {    
      $('.remove').click(function(){
        $(this).parents("fieldset").remove();
      });    
         var intId = $("#fieldwrapper fieldset").length + 1;
        var html = '<fieldset class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 bottom20" id="addField" >';
        html += '<div class="col-md-11" >';
        html += '<label class="col-md-1 label-right left-0">package' + intId + '*</label>';
        html += '<div class=" col-md-11 input-div" id="tracking">';
        html += '<input type="text" class="col-md-11 input-div form-control required" >';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div id="errors" class="txt-left"></div>';
        html += '<label class="col-md-1 label-right">comment</label>';
        html += '<div class="col-md-11 input-div">';
        html += '<input class="form-control" type="text" >';
        html += '</div></div>';

        html += '<div class="col-md-1">';
        html += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove top25" >delete</button>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</fieldset>';


        $("#fieldwrapper").append(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: What type of error do you get?

Comment: in the fiddle, jquery is not included, but that's not the main issue. posting an answer in 1 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to use event delegation when handling events on dynamically created elements.  [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
  if ($("fieldset", "#fieldwrapper").length > 1) {
    $(this).closest("fieldset").remove();
  }
});
```

## Working Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/2qfy6cct/2/

Comment: Thanks! You are AWESOME!